# Postgresql select loop - avoid heavy disk usage

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, disk

I need process a big table row by row. I'm using stored proc with a loop:

```
FOR rec in
    SELECT s.id_main AS id
    FROM big_table b
    LEFT JOIN small_table s ON s.id = b.word_id
    ORDER BY b.id
LOOP
    -- do something
END LOOP;
```

Before first iteration Postgres use a lot of space from temp_tablespaces.
How to avoid havy temp_tablespaces usage during select? (I don't care about a few GB usage).

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE big_table (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    word_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT big_table__pk PRIMARY KEY (id) USING INDEX TABLESPACE corpus
)
TABLESPACE corpus;

CREATE TABLE small_table (
    id int NOT NULL,
    id_main int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT small_table__pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Even a simplified loop use a lot of temp_tablespaces before the first iteration:

```
FOR rec in
    SELECT id
    FROM big_table
    ORDER BY id
LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'id= %, %', rec.id, timeofday();
END LOOP;
```

Why Postgres need some temp_tablespaces storage instead of using PK directly?
Without `ORDER BY id` temp_tablespaces not used.

Comment: Why do you use a loop? Proces your data as a set, not as individual records.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, thanks for your question. Sets is the natural and *usually* the best paradigm when working with DBMS. However, in some cases, for example, when generating a sequence, this led to complex and slow joins by id-2, id-3.. id-n. I have such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by splitting data into small chunks and feed select by chunk. Best performance (depend on server) with "small chunk" size between 100000 and 10000000 rows. In this case no need to change the processing logic within the loop.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fill_tmp()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    chunk_size int = 800000;
    start_id bigint = 0;
    max_id bigint;
    start_time timestamp = clock_timestamp();
    rec record;     
    cnt bigint = 0;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'STARTED %', start_time;
    SELECT max(id) INTO max_id FROM corpus;

    WHILE start_id < max_id LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'cnt= %, time= % sec', cnt, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (clock_timestamp() - start_time));

        FOR rec in
            SELECT m.id_main
            FROM corpus c
            LEFT JOIN word_map m ON m.id = c.word_id
            WHERE c.id > start_id
            ORDER BY c.id
            LIMIT chunk_size
        LOOP
            cnt = cnt + 1;
            -- do work here
        END LOOP;

        SELECT max(id) INTO start_id FROM (
            SELECT id
            FROM corpus
            WHERE id > start_id
            ORDER BY id
            LIMIT chunk_size
         ) q;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Done in % sec; Batch size= %K; % K rows/sec', EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (clock_timestamp() - start_time)),
        chunk_size/1000, round(cnt/EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (clock_timestamp() - start_time))/1000);
END;$$;
```

Comment: With this you might need less `temp_tablespace`, but can you add info on the time needed in comparison to the statement in your question?  How much influence does this change  have in execution time ?

Comment: @Luuk measured time about 10% longer (9.5 hrs vs 8.5hrs in original version), but it can be longer because of server load.

Comment: I have a higher load on the server right now, so the measurement results may not be accurate. Select itself much faster, because it uses memory instead of disk and WHERE by PK also fast.